# AS3 Flip effect leaving a trail?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to create something with a flip effect tutorial from tutplus - http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/effects/iphone-page-transition-flash/

However my flip area is much bigger than the tutorial, it's 900px wide. Everything works fine except that it leaves a trail when the width is that big. You'll see it when you flip it a few times.

Someone else posted the same problem in the comments from last year, but no one replied.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

**Edit:**

Here is a screen shot: http://imageshack.us/f/823/unled2lo.jpg/ (click to enlarge)

The front is purple and the back is white.

As you can see it left a bit of the purple as the page flipped to white.

I couldn't get a screen shot of it turning, but it's even more obvious as the page is actually flipping because the width become narrow which reveals a whole lot more that's left behind on the page.

Comment: What it looks like? Can you add link to screenshot?

Comment: hey alxx, i've added a link of the screenshot to my question. See the purple bit underneath the "the other side" text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you are using create the flip effect using the build in **flash tween classes**, they are absolute rubbish, and very slow if you compare to other third part tween classes. That may be causing the trail! Lee Brimelow has a great video tutorial about how to do exact what you need: http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=91 he is using caurina, but I highly recommend you to replace it with **tweenLight** so far the best tween I ever used.

Ok, thats the walkthrough:

1- Download the files from Lee Brimelow tutorial here http://gotoandlearn.com/files/3dflip.zip

2- Download tweenLight AS3 classes here: http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/

3- copy the **com** folder inside **greensock-as3** and past it inside **3dflip** folder. Now you have all the tween classes you need for your flip!

4- open the flash file **3dflip.fla** and replace the original code (located in the first frame) with this:

```
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import fl.video.*;

con.visible = false;

var flv:FLVPlayback = con.vid.flvp;
flv.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED, onStart);

function onStart(e:Event):void
{
    con.visible = true;
    loading.visible = false;
}

con.vid.spin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cl);
con.tclip.spin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cl);

var isTurning:Boolean = false;

function cl(e:Event):void
{
    if(!isTurning)
    {
        TweenLite.to(con, 1, {rotationY:con.rotationY+180, onComplete:function(){isTurning=false;}});
        isTurning = true;
    }
}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

function loop(e:Event):void
{
    if(con.rotationY > 90 && con.rotationY < 270)
        con.addChild(con.tclip);
    else
        con.addChild(con.vid);
    if(con.rotationY >= 360) con.rotationY = 0;
}
```

Thats it. Now publish and see the result. Now all you have to do is replace the video player with the content that you want!

Answer (score 0):

I would check the state of first side - it seems that it's forgotten on stage when "the other side" kicks in.

Comment: that makes sense. my as3 is limited though, this tutorial is very advanced for me. would you be able to point me to a specific area in the code to fiddle around with?

Comment: Look into `checkFlip` function. Format it properly with tabs (if you didn't already), for it's a mess to look at... Add traces to actions like "toggle visible" and "child added" to see what's going on.

Comment: I updated my answer with a walkthrough of what you need to do! Have a look.